# Cmake refuses to find the correct MinGW folder

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, cmake, qt-creator

I'm completely at a loss here.

I have a C++ project that uses CMake. It used to work, but recently some weird problems came up, so I decided to reinstall the Qt SDK and CMake. However, now I get the following error when trying to build a file:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to
  compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


CMake Error: your C compiler: "C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_C_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed

CMake Error: your C compiler: "C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_C_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

This completely boggles my mind. MinGW is located in `C:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/Tools/`, not `Qt5.0.1`. I tell it so in the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/Tools/MinGW/bin/gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/Tools/MinGW/bing++)
```

I even added `C:/Qt/Qt5.0.2/Tools/MinGW/bin/` to the global `PATH` variable, but this hasn't helped any. CMake keeps thinking it should be in `Qt5.0.1` -- a folder that doesn't exist.

Does anybody know what option I might be overlooking? I've tried just about everything.

Comment: Try to delete your build directory and try to build your project in a new directory. Or just delete CMakeCache.txt in your build directory.

Comment: What else is in the PATH and what order is it in?

Comment: When working with Qt, CMake will use the paths that `qmake` points to and assumes they are correct.  Is it possible that CMake is finding the `qmake` from your old install?  Which `qmake` does it say it finds when it does the FindQT command?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the "not able to compile a simple test program"-issue (Qt Creator, CMake). The reason in my case was that the path to CMake contained forbidden characters: neither spaces nor parentheses are apparently allowed. Uninstalling CMake and reinstalling it under `\ProgramFilesx86\CMake` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have problem same as you and I found the answer for this. It seem be like mingw of Qt has bug so you will get the error like "gcc is broken". Reinstall mingw at http://www.mingw.org/ and link gcc.exe, g++.exe from C:\MingW\Bin\ to your CMake. Build it again and see.

Good luck!